# Synchronous and Asynchronous code confusing definitions

Tags: asynchronous, synchronous, definition, conventions

I might have misunderstood or be missing something but I have to clear this issue:

Asynchronous code means code that gets executed with multiple operations at the same time, without blocking.

Synchronous code means code that gets executed one operation at a time.

But the definition of the word synchronous is occurring at the same time, so that's the other way around isn't it? Why the confusing naming? Is the definition referring to something I am not aware of?

Comment: "Asynchronous" is an adjective that can mean somewhat different things depending on the noun it's modifying.  Usually you can substitute "happening in a different thread or threads of computation" to get the gist. So "async code" is code that runs in different threads.  "Async operation" is one that happens in a thread other than the one being discussed. "Async framework" is a programming environment supporting computation with different threads. Etc. etc. The tricky bit is that each thread considered by itself is working synchronously.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-is-the-difference

Comment: Yeah, terms 'synchronous' and 'asynchronous' are misleading. Read the [article](https://davidkennell.com/2020/05/23/why-async-is-a-misleading-term/) of @dkennell